# AWS - Securing Content From SNS To Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm hoping to find out if there is any way to encrypt message content from SNS to Lambda?  My use case is that I am Publishing JSON content using AWS SDK to a SNS Topic which contains a Subscription using the Lambda protocol to send the content to a Lambda function.

I haven't been able to find any real detail regarding how the Lambda protocol works but I believe it is not encrypting the message content.

I know that I can use a KMS key or whatever to encrypt the content prior to Publishing to the topic but does anyone know of a way to set up SNS or the Lambda subscription to get encryption happening automatically?

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot "automatically" encrypt the payload. Encrypt it before publishing and decrypt it after your receive it at the other end. You can use KMS to manage encryption/decryption keys.

Answer (score 0):

As asdfg mentioned, SNS payloads are not automatically encrypted ([although they are signed](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.verify.signature.html))

You can encrypt the SNS message body yourself if you wish.

Comment: Yip, looks like I'll need to encrypt the content myself.  Thanks for the responses guys!